# Partition of n elements into k groups and the sum of these groups must be the same

Tags: algorithm, list, numbers, computer-science

I need to partition n elements into k groups and the sum of these groups are all the same.

For instance:

I have a list of numbers going from 1 to 99 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5...] and I need to partition the list into 3 groups. The sum of all elements of each groups must be equal. In this example, n=99 and k=3.

What is an efficient and elegant algorithm to achieve this?
I'm just asking for algorithm suggestions to use; I don't want a solution.

Comment: A good start is to know that each partition should sum up to `n / k`.

Comment: if n=50, then will the list contain 1 to 50 ? or random?

Comment: If the numbers are random, it is easy to spot the similarities with the Subset Sum Problem. Particularly, the k-way [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Are the numbers in your list always consecutive and do you need to find only 1 solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by clarifying something: when you say you want an algorithm, but no solution, I have to assume that what you mean is that you want an algorithm that'll give you a solution for `k=3` and `n` any positive integer.

I believe the problem has a solution for any `n >= 5`, provided either `n` or `n+1` is divisible by 3.

This is because the sum `1 + ... + n` equals `n*(n+1)/2`, which is divisible by 3 if and only if either `n` or `n+1` is divisible by 3.

Assuming `n` satisfies these conditions, the algorithm goes like this.

Let `s = [n*(n+1)/2]/3`.

Find the number `m` in the decreasing sequence `n, n-1, n-2, ...,` such that

```
n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + m  <=  s  <  n + (n - 1) + (n - 2 ) + ... + m + (m - 1).
```

Let `h = s - [n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + m]`.

Then `h + [n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + m] = s`, and we have our first sum.

Note that, given how m was obtained, `h` is guaranteed to be in the decreasing sequence `m-2, m-3, ..., 1,` hence is available for our first sum.

We now find the number q in the decreasing sequence `m-1, m-2, ..., h+1, h, h-1, ..., 1,` such that

```
m + (m - 1) + (m - 2) + ... + q  <=  s  <  m + (m - 1) + (m - 2) + ... + q + (q - 1),
```

*keeping in mind that these sums may include `h+1` or `h-1`, but **not** `h`.* **I am abusing the notational conventions for sums** here.

This is where things are getting a bit hairy.

I conjecture that the number `p = s - [m + (m - 1) + (m - 2) + ... + q]` is among the numbers left over (unused) from the original sequence, but I won't prove it. (Exercise for the reader, as they say.)

Then `p + [m + (m - 1) + (m - 2) + ... + q] = s,` and we have have our second sum.

*(Again: the number `h` may **not** be in the sum `[m + (m - 1) + (m - 2) + ... + q]`.)*

The last sum is that of all the remaining numbers, left over from the original sequence.

For example (well, yes, that *is* a solution --- but for illustrative purposes only...):

```
1 + ... + 99 = 99*100/2 = 3*550
             = (99 + 98 + 97 + 96 + 95 + 65)
             + (94 + 93 + 92 + 91 + 90 + 89 + 1)
             + (88 + ... + 66 + 64 + ... + 2).
```

Here `n = 99`, `m = 95`, `h = 65`, `q = 89`, and `p = 1`.